# Wordpress plugin style in index

Tags: php, css, wordpress, plugins, styles

I'm trying to edit a a plugins stylesheet. Yet I can't find any file containing the appropriate CSS.
When I use Chromes developer tool, it says its styled directly in the index site. Yet i can't find it. I've looked through functions.php as well.
The possibility to use !important rules, won't work in my particular examples because i'm dependent on being able to overrule the css in jQuery.
The most important thing is to change the `display: inline-block;` to `display: none;` without using !important

Screenshot below
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Hello  plugin  CSS  in usually   in the  plugin  folder  just  check  in there  and are loaded all  in the index  that's why  you  see  it  in the index

Answer (score 0):

I've found it via the FTP, in there there was an additional "app.css.twig" file that wasn't showing up in wordpress